# Is it possible to move an Event to the bottom of a day cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar with month view, I want to move an event to the bottom of a day cell. Is it possible and how?

I have made a picture of my goal, I made ​​it with the help of Google Chrome's Inspect element

[image]

Comment: You can do a workaround in the css file in the `fc-event-hori` class. Set `top` to `90px`

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this? I still haven't figured out how. And there is no "fc-event-hori" class.

Comment: is it possible to set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: I cannot or we all cannot do something without seeing some code. So I would say that you can try this ´position: absolute; bottom: 0;´ out. This is just a suggestion....

Comment: Solution with ``position: absolute; bottom: 0;`` breaks markup totally. Any pure CSS solution could not help. Other approach is using JS, but the library generates such HTML structure, that it seems impossible in any affordable way to solve the problem - need a lot of hours for it.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to do it at v.3.9.0 only using CSS

```
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

and add a class to yout event and use:

```
.fc-event.your-class{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: fullcalendar fixed event]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so please understand. I have tried everything that would come to mind to be able to do something like this. With their demo they have for FullCalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ I immediately see that it is using tables for the structure. There is a major problem with this. Tables have their own predefined structures and allow you to order things in a specific table driven format.. obviously right...

Problem with this is by definition each has a defined height built from the content inside. If you position absolute (which is what you would need for your task) they do one of two things. Disappear (if done on content) or lose defined table column width. They then are unable to move around unless you know a calculated amount.

So what you would need to do (without having actual code in front to see how you are populating the fields) is to count each element that has status within the given day and give each position absolute. For every given item that you want to be at the bottom you calculate that in and then you have to move each individual item up.

Basically this would not work very well and would be very complicated. I don't recommend using this calendar for what you're trying unless you can somehow change the structure to something a bit more flexible.

If someone does find a way great! But sadly there was no solution that made sense from their provided demo for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about FullCalendar but normally `vertical-align: bottom` will put the data on bottom. Problem is it will place ALL data on bottom, not as you shown on the image.

to solve this particular problem you can place a new table inside the cell so you end up with :

```
<table> //Main Table
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> // new table
                <tr>
                    <td> data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr> // vertical align : bottom
                    <td>custom event</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but then you end with lot of ugly code. (also you may want to use `rowspan=2` when there is no custom event)

Another apporach would be to have always a space for this 'custom event'
Doing this you only need to use a `position:relative; padding-bottom:30px;` on the `<td>` and then the custom event item using `position: absolute; bottom:0`.

this have a new problem where you always have a padding bottom of `30px` even when u don't have a custom event. (this can be mitigated by adding the padding on the fly with `JavaScript`)

not sure if this actually helps you, but those are the things that came to my mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this on fullcalendar-2.1.1 using the demo default.html.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2014-09-01',
                isStickied: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2014-09-07',
                end: '2014-09-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-09-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-09-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2014-09-11',
                end: '2014-09-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-09-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-09-12T12:30:00',
                isStickied: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2014-09-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-09-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2014-09-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2014-09-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2014-09-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2014-09-28'
            }
        ],
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
            if (event.isStickied) {
                $(element).css('position', 'absolute');
                $(element).css('bottom', '0');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

You will also need to modify fullcalendar.css line 648 for .fc-content-skeleton to have:

```
height: 108px;
```

This will assume that your monthly calendar view will always have a fixed row height of 108px like in the demo.